# SQL Server 2008: updating and keeping tracking of anuual price increase

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a project right now where I need to update the prices for a list of products. The prices for 1/1/2007 to 12/31/2011 are given and I need to increase those prices by 5% each year, until the end of 2015.

Here is what I have. But I am getting stuck on updating the prices (ie 5% increase). I keep getting an error message about duplicate data. Thanks in advance for any help/hints !

**Error message:**

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Procedure update_history, Line 9
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_*PriceCha*_207F7DE23A81B327'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.PriceChange_History'.

**Tables:**

```
create table PriceChange
(ProductID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 StartDate DATE,
 EndingDate DATE,
 UnitPrice MONEY);


ALTER TABLE PriceChange ADD FOREIGN KEY (ProductID) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ProductID)


create table PriceChange_History
(History_ProductID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 History_StartDate DATE,
 History_EndingDate DATE,
 History_UnitPrice MONEY,
 Modified_date datetime,
 ChangeType varchar(20) );

ALTER TABLE PriceChange_History 
ADD FOREIGN KEY (History_ProductID) REFERENCES PRODUCT(ProductID)
```

**Triggers**

```
create trigger [insert_history] on PriceChange
for insert
as  
    insert PriceChange_History (History_ProductID, History_StartDate, 
                                History_EndingDate, History_UnitPrice,
                                Modified_date, ChangeType)
        select 
            ProductID, StartDate, EndingDate, UnitPrice,
            GETDATE(), 'INSERTED'
        from inserted

create trigger [update_history] on PriceChange
for update
as
   insert PriceChange_History(History_ProductID, History_StartDate,
                              History_EndingDate, History_UnitPrice,
                              Modified_date, ChangeType)
       select 
           ProductID, StartDate, EndingDate, UnitPrice,
           GETDATE(), 'BEFORE UPDATE'
       from deleted

   insert PriceChange_History(History_ProductID, History_StartDate,
                              History_EndingDate, History_UnitPrice,
                              Modified_date, ChangeType)
      select     
          ProductID, StartDate, EndingDate, UnitPrice,
          GETDATE(), 'AFTER UPDATE'
      from inserted
```

**INSERT + UPDATE**

```
INSERT INTO PriceChange 
VALUES(1,'1/1/2007', '12/31/2011', 500) <---  this will record the query into both pricechange and pricechange history

UPDATE PriceChange 
SET UnitPrice = (UnitPrice * 1.05),
    StartDate = '1/1/2012',
    EndingDate = '12/31/2012' 
WHERE 
    ProductID = 1

UPDATE PriceChange 
SET UnitPrice = (UnitPrice * 1.05),
    StartDate = '1/1/2013',
    EndingDate = '12/31/2013' 
WHERE 
    ProductID = 1

UPDATE PriceChange 
SET UnitPrice = (UnitPrice * 1.05),
    StartDate = '1/1/2014',
    EndingDate = '12/31/2014' 
WHERE 
    ProductID = 1

UPDATE PriceChange 
SET UnitPrice = (UnitPrice * 1.05),
    StartDate = '1/1/2015',
    EndingDate = '12/31/2015' 
WHERE
    ProductID = 1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 4):

price_history has PK on ProductID so it cannot have duplicate products. I would add identity primary key.

Comment: @Hciree if this answer helped solve your problem, be sure to click the Checkmark button next to it to mark it as answered!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'm noticing is that your PriceChange table data could actually be derived from the PriceChange_History table.

If there is a reason you must store the PriceChange table rather than providing it through a view, I would start with adding an identity column as a PK to both tables.  I strongly recommend tables always have a simple identity column...you'll be glad you did it sooner or later :-)  Next, add an appropriate unique, clustered key to PriceChange: ProductId, StartDate, EndDate.  Next, relate the PriceChange_History table to the PriceChange identity PK instead of productId.  Finally, add an appropriate unique clustered key to PriceChange_History: PriceChangeId, ModifiedDate.

Now you are ready to update the related triggers, functions, etc. accordingly, and will be able to insert multiple PriceChange rows into the PriceChange_History table.

Update
Just from your current history table, the current pricing information can be derived in a view with the logic below:

```
Select 
    LastChangeDetails.ProductId,
    ProductChangeDetails.StartDate,
    ProductChangeDetails.EndDate,
    ProductChangeDetails.UnitPrice
    (
        Select 
            History_ProductId, 
            Max(Modified_date) as LastModifiedDate
        From PriceChange_History
    ) as LastChange
Join PriceChange_History as LastChangeDetails
    on LastChangeDetails.History_productId = LastChange.ProductId
and LastChangeDetails.modified_Date = LastChange.LastChangeDate --assumes the most recently modified information is the 'most correct'
```

Comment: Thanks Rose! You mentioned i can use 1 table instead of 2? if so thats even better. But how would i go about that? do i add new columns in PriceChange_History? sorry this is my first time dealing with SQL. 

main goal of this is to for me update the prices, and when i am done i can do a query and look up the price at the time of 9/11/2012

Comment: Sorry for the late reply Hciree...I'll post some suggested structures/code shortly if you're still interested...

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the view derivation logic.  Happy querying :-)